# Python installing PyQt4 module to custom software

Tags: python, import, module, pyqt4

This is something I've been researching for past few hours but so far nothing come out of it.

Basically I have software that use Python 2.5.5. It does not have QT module in it.

So in my attempt to install it I did this.

Downloaded executable QT PyQt4-4.10.2-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.4-x64. Run Exe. It installed in python 2.7 site-packages.

Then I moved that folder to my software Python 2.5.5. Now there was no site-packages folder so I created it.

Next step was to go over this instruction http://docs.python.org/2/install/ and use Alternate installation: Windows (the prefix scheme) with my file location from inside program. But I cant run python setup.py install --prefix="\Temp\Python" (with my location of python) because python is not defined and so on. I'm pretty sure thats the wrong way to do it. So how or where do I look for information as to how to do it? The software itself dont have any documentation.

Thanks, bye.

Answer (score 0):

That binary version of PyQt4 only supports python2.7, so no matter what you do, you won't get it to run with python2.5.

The last `PyQt4` version with a binary for python2.5 is [PyQt4.9.4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.9.4/), so if you want to have any chance of making this work you should try with this version.

Note however that the software you distribute like this will also *only* run on python2.5.

Comment: Heya thank you so much for this reply ! However I'm getting error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code 193 and as far as I can track it down it comes to 32 bit vs 64 bit version of python/qt... is there pyqt 2.5 for 64 bit? I cant find it anywhere :(

Comment: Yea, i almost couldn't find it either... But courtesy of the WaybackMachine - [here](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20120614191014/http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download) you go...

Comment: Heya, Thanks ! That sorted the 193 error! And now I got another one... ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.... But now I have no clue whats wrong. This is so annoying wrr! I'm thinking I can import PyQt4 but problems start when I try to do this : from PyQt4 import PyCore, PyGui modules. Maybe I dont need those functions in 1st place. All I need to do is to just connect program action to ui somehow. So if I type in name in UI then that name will  be used to search... do I need those modules for it? QtGui looks to be used when I want to code from scratch UI.

Comment: I mean QtCore/QtGui. Its as if he finds the site-packages folder and import QT but then it cant import modules... This is the Script I run:`import sys
print sys.path

sys.path.append("C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages")
import PyQt4
print PyQt4

from PyQt4 import QtGui`

Comment: There should be some clue in the traceback about which module could not be loaded - my guess would be on `sip`. If you only copied the PyQt4 folder, you probably missed it. Note that your way of packaging isn't really best practice. Maybe you should look into something like pyinstaller or cxFreeze.

Comment: Heya, nope all error information I get is the one I pasted above. The module is the one I try to import so if I type `from PyQt4 import QtGui` then that errors. If I type QtCore then Core errors its as if he cant find it there or not sure. I'm not sure how to install it properly to that python there is no install, setup, config. There is ConfigParser tho. As far as I can tell that python is verys tripped down :( I can zip it and email it to you if that would help. I started reading about pyinstaller - it sounds like it should help me ! Will get back to you asap! Thanks!!!